# No clear path for saving(persisting) states of RecyclerView which is inside of a Fragment coped with a ViewPager

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, persistence

Question:
**How do I persist the RecyclerView's data**

Scenario:
**RecyclerView inside of a Fragment(say A) coped with ViewPager along with 4 other Fragments(B,C,D,E)**

RecyclerView is populated with PostRecylcerViewAdapter adapter class. And the data is fetched from Firebase.

**Problem:**
Screen rotations, flipping between the Fragments reloads everything resulting in multiple connections/downloading from Firebase.

**What I already know:**
That I have to store the states maybe using savedInstanceState, and handle screen rotations, bundle/parcelables etc.

**But in this case, how?**

**Components and structure:** 
A, B, C, D, E - 5 Fragments with ViewPager in their Parent Activity's layout(say HomeActivity).

RecylerView inside of a Fragment say **B**.
RecyclerView Adapter is attached inside the onDataChanged() method of Firebase Database Reference.

**So how?**

Answer (score 0):

Try add that in fragment B `onCreate()`:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

It will keep your fragment alive during rotation changes.